# smartgwt listgrid population from excel file data

Tags: smartgwt

i am providing a support to import the excel file data to the smartgwt ListGrid as a ListGridRecord. and im doing it by providing a textarea on my UI. when i paste the excel data to UI texarea. on Tab out,all the record should be populated into my listgrid. any idea how to do it. Thanks